# gitlab-ci docker | using build files outside container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey fellow developers,

I use gitlab-ci, with my own gitlab-runner running as a docker image on the server (Ubuntu 22.04, Docker 20.10, Docker image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest).

It builds, using `npm install && npm run build` a CRA build, this works.

I want to use the generated CRA build (bunch of javascript & co files) outside of the docker container. Copy it in a /var/www/html folder on the server side (same server than the docker container).

How can I do that ?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I cannot use `docker cp` since I'm 'inside' the container when the gitlab-ci job runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally end up by creating a **second runner** with **shell executor**, building and deploying the app.

But there was a way to do what I did want, **mount a volume** in the container from the host where my build is used, and put the build in it, but it's **more problems and code** than using a second "shell" runner.

Ty